# Semantically, why does epoll_wait sends me EPOLLIN, after read end had been shut down?

Tags: linux, epoll

The question is straightforward. The `shutdown(..., SHUT_RD)` was called on the socket after `read` has returned `zero`. The `epoll_wait` keeps sending me `EPOLLIN` event for the socket.
I know I can, and must do, in my situation, call `epoll_ctl` to modify the event mask. Naive thoughts lead me to think that, if `close` removes record from the `epoll` list, then `shutdown` had to mark appropriate socket end.

The question is, ***semantically***, why `epoll_wait` do report me with read available, given that ***`read` returned `0` socket were shut down for reading***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`epoll_wait()` will report `EPOLLIN` if trying to read from the socket would return immediately rather than blocking.

Once you do `shutdown(..., SHUT_RD);` all calls to `read()` return `0` immediately. Since it won't block, `epoll_wait()` reports that the socket is readable.

Answer (score 1):

It is also semantically reasonable. For example, if you receive `EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP` and successfully read data from it (because your peer sent both data and `FIN`), you might not close the connection. However, if no new event is sent, you will miss the only opportunity to close the connection. In this case, repeated `EPOLLIN` events can help.